# Using @discardableResult for Closures in Swift

Tags: swift, closures, swift3

Swift 3 has [introduced](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0047-nonvoid-warn.md) the `@discardableResult` annotation for functions to disable the warnings for an unused function return value.

I'm looking for a way to silence this warning for closures.

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
func f(x: Int) -> Int -> Int {
  func g(_ y: Int) -> Int {
    doSomething(with: x, and: y)
    return x*y
  }
  return g
}
```

In various places I call `f` once to obtain a closure `g` which I then call repeatedly:

```
let g = f(5)
g(3)
g(7)
g(11)
```

In most places I'm only interested in the side effects of the nested call to `doSomething`, and not in the return value of the closure `g`. With Swift 3, there are now dozens of warnings in my project for the unused result. Is there a way to suppress the warnings besides changing the calls to `g` to `_ = g(...)` everywhere? I couldn't find a place where I could place the `@discardableResult` annotation.

Comment: please take a look at this :) https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/

Comment: It doesn't seem like this is possible, but it seems like something that should be added. You might want to see if there's any discussion on it: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution

Comment: How do the API Design Guidelines help here?

Comment: It doesn't, you should just generally look at it considering your function names are meaningless :) also an FYI that type of function definition syntax doesn't work in Swift 3. You'll need to put your return function's parameters in ()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to apply that attribute to a closure. You could capture your closure in another that discards the result:

```
func discardingResult<T, U>(_ f: @escaping (T) -> U) -> (T) -> Void {
  return { x in _ = f(x) }
}

let g = f(5)
g(3)  // warns
let h = discardingResult(g)
h(4)  // doesn't warn
```

Comment: 6 years and many Swift versions later still a brilliant idea!

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for an answer to this recently, and I've found another way (a newer way) to do this!
It could arguably be overkill for some simple problems, but I just thought that this is an interesting yet neat approach that's worth sharing.

Say you have a closure that doubles an integer value:

```
let double = { (int: Int) -> Int in
    return int * 2
}
```

With Swift 5.0 ([SE-0216](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0216-dynamic-callable.md)) introducing the `@dynamicCallable` attribute, you can "wrap" your closure with `@discardableResult` by creating a dynamically callable `class` or `struct` as such:

```
// same for struct, except without the need of an initializer

@dynamicCallable
class DiscardableResultClosure<T, U> {

    var closure: (T) -> U

    @discardableResult
    func dynamicallyCall(withArguments args: [Any]) -> U {
        let arg = args.first as! T
        return self.closure(arg)
    }

    // implicit for struct
    init(closure: @escaping (T) -> U) {
        self.closure = closure
    }

}

double(5) // warning: result of call to function returning 'Int' is unused

let discardableDouble = DiscardableResultClosure(closure: double)
discardableDouble(5) // * no warning *
```

Even better, in Swift 5.2 ([SE-0253](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0253-callable.md)), you can create a dynamically callable `struct` using a built-in `callAsFunction` method without going through the trouble of using the attribute `@dynamicCallable` (or using class) with its sometimes cumbersome declaration.

```
struct DiscardableResultClosure<T, U> {

    var closure: (T) -> U

    @discardableResult
    func callAsFunction(_ arg: T) -> U {
        return closure(arg)
    }

}

let discardableDouble = DiscardableResultClosure(closure: double)
discardableDouble(5) // * no warning *
```