# @discardableResult seems to be ignored in protocols when returning a closure

Tags: swift

Recently I came across an issue when designing some of my APIs with `@discardableResult` applied to a closure that is being returned by some method. Protocols and classes I used to reproduce the issue are listed below.

`SomeProtocol.swift`:

```swift
// SomeProtocol.swift

protocol SomeProtocol {
    @discardableResult func foo() -> () -> Void
}
```

`SomeClass.swift`:

```swift
// SomeClass.swift

class SomeClass: SomeProtocol {
    @discardableResult func foo() -> () -> Void {
        return {
            print("foo")
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the use case:

```swift
let first = SomeClass()
first.foo() // No errors

let second: SomeProtocol = SomeClass()
second.foo() // "Function is unused" error
```

I've done a little bit of research and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39712543/using-discardableresult-for-closures-in-swift) question, but it seems like it is not the case with the latest Swift versions anymore. I was unable to track down the version of Swift in which the error is gone, but in Swift 5.5.1 which I'm currently using there's the compiler error when method marked with `@discardableResult` required by a protocol returns a closure. There seem to be no errors when using a concrete type instead, as I mentioned in the use case.

Am I missing something or is it a Swift design choice?

Comment: Yes! I faced the similar problem with playgrounds, it only reproduces in xcode projects for me.

Comment: That makes sense, doesn’t it? In a playground, no value is truly discarded, because they’re all printed on the sidebar

Comment: I don't think the linked question is relevant at all. You are not trying to ignore the result of the `{ print("foo") }` closure (it doesn't even have a result). You are trying to ignore the result of `foo`.

Comment: I had a look at the [only place](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/63f355fde0172b530178abd84f066322e81dcf3b/lib/Sema/TypeCheckStmt.cpp#L1337) in the source code where this error is emitted, and I can't see anything deliberately written about this class/protocol divide. I think this is very likely a bug, though I cannot say with 100% certainty.